# npm completely won't work: "Error: Cannot find module 'isarray'"

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, package.json

So every time I try us any npm command I get the same error:

```
module.js:472
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'isarray'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:32:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Even when I try running `npm install isarray` I get the same exact error.
I've tried uninstalling the dependencies and then running `npm install` and I get the same error. I've tried completely reinstalling npm AND node and I still get the same error.

If I need this package to install this package I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Try to delete your node_modules directory and make a fresh install of your dependencies.

Comment: I have already done that but when I try to fresh install with `npm install` I get the same exact error as before.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this was cause of node and npm version.

Try to update your node and npm version.

First, Node update is

> //Clean node Cache
>
> sudo npm cache clean -f
>
> //Install n Module
>
> sudo npm install -g n
>
> //Install stable Node version Using n Module
>
> sudo n stable

IF this is not worked, then use 'nvm' (In my case, below is worked.)

> nvm install 8.10.0

You can check your node version by 'node -v'

Second, npm update.

> sudo npm install -g npm

You can also check your npm version by 'npm -v'

I hope this will be helpful!

Comment: It worked for me. I try to update npm in C9 and get this error. Follow 007 guide's steps, I fixed it. Thanks